# What is the difference between KMP and Z algorithm of string pattern matching?

Tags: string, algorithm, matching

In KMP algorithm we preprocess the pattern to find the longest prefix which we used to skip characters while matching.

while in Z- algorithm we first make a new string 
new_string = pattern + 'x' + string 
where x = character that doesn't exist in both pattern and string 
After making the new_string we preprocess the new_string to find longest prefix and if the lent of prefix is equal to pattern length then we found the pattern

Both have time complexity of O(m+n).

so what is the difference between these two algorithms and which one is best to use?

Comment: The Z-algorithm and the KMP have similar time complexities and they can be used interchangeably. It is up to the choice of the developer which one they find easier to understand and code.

Answer (score 2):

Is not always about time complexity, the storage complexity are the playing role here:

Knuth Morris Pratt:

Worst-case performance : Θ(m) preprocessing + Θ(n) matching

Worst-case space complexity : Θ(m)

Z algorithm:

Worst-case performance: Θ(m+n) preprocessing and matching

worst-case space complexity: Θ(n+m)

Besides, you can use the idea of searching prefix and suffix for other usages beside searching a pattern, so you could have other reasons to do the analytics on particular information

Also I would recommend for other matching algorithms for some tasks even if they have worse time complexity like Boyer-moore, it all depend on the situation

Comment: O(m) + O(n) = O(m + n), but your answer makes it seem otherwise.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar why so? I didn't said they have difference in the performance, I said there's a space complexity difference and also the preprocessing can be done before the matching so you could save even on the performance side

Comment: I didn't say either that you said otherwise, but the notation you used might make the OP think, especially if they're new, that `O(m) + O(n)` and `O(m + n)` are different. If you read your two "_Worst-case performance_" lines, you'll see why that might be.